Why is PHP or jQuery removing a concatanated </a> end tag in an inline JS script, and closing tags itself?
I have this PHP code, which outputs some headings and an inline jQuery script:
<?php
echo '<h2>Test</h2>';
?>

<div>
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="test">
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    var testVar = 'Some info from a variable.';
    $( '<div id="test-id" class="test-class">' + testVar + ' <a href="/test?test=1">Test?</a></div>' ).insertAfter( $( '#placeholder' ) );
});
</script>
</form>
</div>

<?php
echo '<h2>End of test</h2>';
?>

This inserts a test-id div with a link inside to after the placeholder div.
This works locally, but when I test this on a live server, if I view source, I see the line under testVar has been changed to this, it's like the PHP or jQuery is stripping the end </a> tag and closing off the script and form:
$( '<div id="test-id" class="test-class">' + testVar + ' <a href="/test?test=1">Test?</script>
</form>
</div>' ).insertAfter( $( '#placeholder' ) );


I believe that's more the browser's handling when trying to render your form, closing tags where the parser believes them to be missing. Maybe try moving that script some before the closing </body> to see if that makes the difference.

@PaulT. But i'm seeing that in view source? aswell as the DOM? I've tried moving the script but the same issue.

Ok, well, I'll have to check later, as being on a phone, no way that I can easily test that at the moment.

If you see it when you view the received source code, then it can't be jQuery's fault.  Is this supposed to be a "stand-alone" script, are you requesting a PHP file that contains nothing but the above, directly? Or does this content get passed through something else?

Found the issue, it was in relation to some consent application automatically attempting to block scripts, and in doing that was replacing the code output in the page, without me knowing
